# How to get image data as a string from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, tensorflow

Discaimer: Im new. Im using OpenCV to capture images from webcam, which means images are represented in numpy arrays. However, then i need to feed them to a tensorflow graph as input, which currently takes image data as string as input.

Curently, im saving the frames, and then loading them again with

```
image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
```

and them feeding them to the graph like this

```
resized_input_values = sess.run(decoded_image_tensor,
                                  {image_data_tensor: image_data})
```

I would like to cut out the middle ground of saving them and loading them again

Comment: You can feed numpy arrays. It's not the best option, however

Comment: @Sharky why not? What is the best option?

Comment: Take a look https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/overview 
Maybe you'll find your answer, or add some context to your question

Comment: Hello, If you graph taking input image as string why you are not converting it into to string or you didn't show that part?.